# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de traducir "overwhelming"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Con frecuencia oigo la palabra `overwhelming`. Me suena potente e intento incorporarla a mi vocabulario en inglés. Sin embargo, cuando busco sus [posibles traducciones](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=overwhelming) me encuentro con unas cuantas:

> - ( too powerful )
>
>   - arrollador/a
>   - apabullante
>   - aplastante, avasallante
>   - avasallador/a
> - ( irresistible )
>
>   - irresistible
> - ( feeling )
>
>   - acuciante
>   - incontenible
>   - abrumador/a

Como algunas de ellas me parecen contradictorias entre sí, me pregunto: ¿cuál es la forma más correcta de traducir esta palabra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posiblemente, no hay "mejor manera" de traducir `overwhelming`. Es decir, no hay una relación uno-a-uno entre el inglés y el español y la mejor traducción ("mejor" en el sentido de que mantiene o expresa mejor el significado, y en la medida de lo posible embellece estilísticamente) depende mucho del contexto.

Por ejemplo, a la lista que aportas en la pregunta podría añadir `agobiado` (o `agobiante`), si se usa para describir al sujeto que está bajo presión. Podría usar `apabullante`, pero `agobiado` suena mejor para mi (en lo que por supuesto es una **opción personal**).

Por el contrario si quisiera decir

> I felt the *overwhelming* feeling to do XYZ

favorecería `irresistible` en lugar de `agobiador/a`.

> Sentí el *irresistible* deseo de hacer XYZ (tomarme un helado, por ejemplo)

Bajo otro contexto, sí favorecería

> La *agobiante* sensación de XYZ (de la carga de trabajo, por ejemplo)

Otras posibilidades podría incluir

- sobrecogedor
- insoportable
- desbordante
- incontenible

e incluso

- contundente (The evidence was overwhelming)
- extraordinario (The view was overwhelming)

Y por supuesto escoger una sobre otra podría depender del contexto y de la forma en la que quieras expresar el significado original o matizar el sentimiento.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, Diego. Muchas gracias por ella. Consulté el significado en general, cuando vea su uso en casos concretos volveré a esta respuesta para cotejar a qué caso corresponde : )